# show picker view content on tap of button or picker itself in swiftui?

Tags: button, swiftui, picker

Unable to click on Image, picker is oopening ontap of Choose but not on drowDown image as shown in image.

[image]

I tried to place button too inplace of Image, but unable to acheive it.
Below is the enum values:

```
enum ProfileRelationshipSignUp: String {
        case NONE = "Choose"
        case FATHER = "Father"
        case MOTHER = "Mother"
        case GUARDIAN = "Guardian"
        case RELATIVE = "Relative"
        case CHILD = "Child"
        case SIBLING = "Sibling"
        case COLLEAGUE = "Colleague"
        case SPOUSE = "Spouse"
    }
```

This is the view where picker and image is created

struct RelationShipView: View {

```
    @State var selectedRelationship: ProfileRelationshipSignUp = .NONE

    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Picker(selection: $selectedRelationship, label: HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 5) {
                    Text(microAppViewModel.users[indexValue].relationshipLabel)
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .font(Font.custom("Lato-Regular", size: valueSize))
                }, content: {
                    Text("Choose").tag(ProfileRelationshipSignUp.NONE)
                    Text("Mother").tag(ProfileRelationshipSignUp.MOTHER)
                    Text("Father").tag(ProfileRelationshipSignUp.FATHER)
                    Text("Guardian").tag(ProfileRelationshipSignUp.GUARDIAN)
                    Text("Relative").tag(ProfileRelationshipSignUp.RELATIVE)
                    Text("Child").tag(ProfileRelationshipSignUp.CHILD)
                    Text("Sibling").tag(ProfileRelationshipSignUp.SIBLING)
                    Text("Colleague").tag(ProfileRelationshipSignUp.COLLEAGUE)
                    Text("Spouse").tag(ProfileRelationshipSignUp.SPOUSE)
                })
                    .onChange(of: selectedRelationship, perform: { value in
                        switch(value) {
                        case .NONE: microAppViewModel.users[indexValue].relationshipLabel = "Choose"
                        case .FATHER: microAppViewModel.users[indexValue].relationshipLabel = "Father"
                        case .MOTHER: microAppViewModel.users[indexValue].relationshipLabel = "Mother"
                        case .GUARDIAN: microAppViewModel.users[indexValue].relationshipLabel = "Guardian"
                        case .RELATIVE: microAppViewModel.users[indexValue].relationshipLabel = "Relative"
                        case .CHILD: microAppViewModel.users[indexValue].relationshipLabel = "Child"
                        case .SIBLING: microAppViewModel.users[indexValue].relationshipLabel = "Sibling"
                        case .COLLEAGUE: microAppViewModel.users[indexValue].relationshipLabel = "Colleague"
                        case .SPOUSE: microAppViewModel.users[indexValue].relationshipLabel = "Spouse"
                        }
                    }).onAppear(perform: {
                        selectedRelationship = ProfileRelationshipSignUp(rawValue: microAppViewModel.users[indexValue].relationshipLabel) ?? .NONE
                    })
                    .pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                
                Image("DropDown")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: 12, height: 12, alignment: .center)
                    .padding(.top, 5)
                
            }
            Divider()
                .frame(height: 1.0)
        }
    }
}
```